# gtk_widget_destroy on GtkFileChooserDialog results in segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, gtk, gtk3

I have a problem with my first GTK+ Application. I tried to implement saving to an XML File. It works like it should but sometimes, the program crashes at gtk_widget_destroy(save_dialog) with a segmentation fault. I really have no clue why this is happening.

I hope someone can may help me.

Code of the function:

```
static void save_file_from_source_view(gboolean is_save_as)
{
  GtkTextIter start, end;
  char *text_content;

  gtk_text_buffer_get_start_iter(GTK_TEXT_BUFFER(text_editor_buffer), &start);
  gtk_text_buffer_get_end_iter(GTK_TEXT_BUFFER(text_editor_buffer), &end);
  text_content = gtk_text_buffer_get_text(GTK_TEXT_BUFFER(text_editor_buffer), &start, &end, FALSE);

  if(is_save_as||last_filename==NULL)
  {
    GtkWidget *save_dialog;
    gint result;

    save_dialog = gtk_file_chooser_dialog_new("Save File", GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_SAVE, "Cancel", GTK_RESPONSE_CANCEL, "Save", GTK_RESPONSE_ACCEPT, NULL);
    gtk_file_chooser_set_do_overwrite_confirmation(GTK_FILE_CHOOSER(save_dialog), TRUE);
    gtk_file_chooser_set_current_name(GTK_FILE_CHOOSER(save_dialog), last_filename!=NULL? last_filename:"untitled.xml");
    result = gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(save_dialog));
    if(result == GTK_RESPONSE_ACCEPT)
    {
      char *filename;
      filename = gtk_file_chooser_get_filename(GTK_FILE_CHOOSER(save_dialog));
      save_file(filename, text_content);
      g_free(last_filename);
      last_filename = malloc(sizeof(filename));
      g_print("Got here 1\n");
      strcpy(last_filename, filename);
      g_print("Got here 2\n");
      g_free(filename);
      g_print("Got here 3\n");
    }
    g_print("Got here 4\n");
    gtk_widget_destroy(save_dialog); // Crashes here
    g_print("Got here 5\n");
  }
  else
  {
    save_file(last_filename, text_content);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Got here 1
Got here 2
Got here 3
Got here 4
Segemntation fault (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sure you want the length of the string:

```
last_filename = malloc(strlen(filename) + 1);
```

instead of the size of a pointer to `char` (as you did):

```
last_filename = malloc(sizeof(filename));
```

Don't forget to call `free(last_filename)` at the end in order to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: Oh... Sometimes one is not able to see the woods for the trees... Yeah... thank you :)

Comment: Edit: `last_filename` is free'd above `last_filename = malloc(...)` because it only has to be overwritten there and will last until the program ends otherwise. So I don't need to free it somewhere else.

Comment: @DMCKITT I don't get you, your functión doesn't return `last_filename`, thus, the space requested by `last_filename`is never freed and results in a memory leak, the rules are: one call to `free` for each call to `malloc`, also, you should check the return of `malloc` or ... since you have glib at your disposal, take advantage of it: use `g_malloc`

Comment: Thats correct, `last_filename` is a global variable, defined in the header file.
So, the variable is free'd before the malloc happens.
This whole program is just to get an understanding of GTK. There are no error checkings and also no return checkings at all. I will include them of course when I start the first real project. But good idea to use g_malloc instead, even though I don't now yet whats the difference. But I will have a look :)
Thank you for your input.

Comment: Ahhhh ... ok! I didn't pay attention to that ;) the difference between `malloc` and `g_malloc`: `g_malloc` acts similar to `new` in C++, you don't need to check if the call succeeded: https://github.com/GNOME/glib/blob/master/glib/gmem.c

Comment: Thank you :) I already looked it up by myself already, but as I can see in the source of `g_malloc`, it will just terminate the program with an error, so does a NULL-Pointer-Exception, if the malloc fails. But I also see there is Memory-Leak tracing possibilities in glib... so I will use `g_malloc` from now on :)